# how to disable save as option of browser

Tags: php

how we can  disable save as option of browser by php?

Comment: If you dont want users to save your content, then dont put it online.

Comment: Add watermark is an alternative method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not do that.

Answer (score 7):

Impossible. The user already has your page. It was transferred to their computer before it could be displayed on their screen. At this point no code you write can stop them from keeping what they already have.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is processed server-side. Your browser is client-side. Thus, you can not achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

its not possible becaouse browser is on client side.

Answer (score 0):

PHP stands for **P**HP: **H**ypertext ***P**re-processer*. It can only process your PHP script. Thus, when you run your script, it just generates HTML output(in most cases), and sends that to the users browser. When you have already done the handling on the server side, and it has been sent to the browser, PHP can't change it. This means that this is not possible via PHP. You might be able to disable Control+S via Javascript, though.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to disable the "save" with PHP if you access the COM elements of the browser and control them before outputting. Google "accessing COM objects with PHP"